# A convex objective function will be convex regardless of constraints?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, constraints

Let's say I have a convex objective function. The boilerplate example is $z=x^2+y^2$. Now, I also have some constraint, $f(x,y)=0$. Is it true that the constrained optimization problem must be convex as well? I suspect this is the case, but have only rough intuition to back it up and was wondering if there is a proof.

---

My intuitive argument is that if the objective function is convex, it is always "curved downwards" (where "down" is in the direction of the objective function). Now, since the constraint can only add a condition in the x-y plane, it can't introduce any curvature in the z-direction (the direction of the objective function). So, the convexity of the objective function in that direction must be preserved.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The problem is only convex if the constraints are convex as well.

Comment: Prove that if a objective function is convex, then regardless of any constraints, the optimization problem will remain convex. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: @copper.hat, can you provide an example where we have a convex objective function and then we add a constraint (whatever constraint you want) and this makes the curve of intersection non-convex?

Comment: The intersection could be a discrete set of points. For example, $|x|=1$ will only allow two points $\pm 1$.

Comment: Let's restrict ourselves to at least 2 variables (so including the objective function, we have three dimensions).

Comment: Well, it is not clear to me what you are looking for, extend the previous comment, then the set $\|x\|=1$ is not convex.

Comment: Why not, $||x||=1$ is just two planes if we have two variables, $x$ and $y$. And planes are convex, no?

Comment: Let's say I have the objective function: $z=x^2+y^2$. This is convex. Which means that any tangent plane lies completely below the function. Now, if you include a constraint (say $x=1$), the locus of intersection will now be $z=1+y^2$. This is still a convex function as any tangent to the new curve is completely below it. My question is, can one add a constraint such that this property no longer holds.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, good luck. The set $\|x\|=1$ is a circle, sphere, whatever in $n$ dimensions. I don't understand your two planes comment.

Comment: Ahh, I see. In that case, it is a circle when considering the x-y plane. But when we include the objective function ($z$ axis), it is a cylinder. The convexity requirement is along the $z$ axis as defined in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

The concept that delivers results in convex optimization is that the objective function have a convex epigraph, that is, the set of points $\{(x,f(x)):x\in\text{ constraint set}\}$ be convex.  This will fail if the constraint set is non-convex.

Indeed, Rockafellar's 1970 book *Convex Analysis* defines the term *convex function* (on p.23) as follows

> Let $f$ be a function whose values are real or $\pm\infty$ and whose domain is a subset $S$ of $R^n$. The set $$\{(x,\mu)|x\in S,\mu\in R,\mu\ge f(x)\}$$ is called the *epigraph* of $f$ and is denoted by $\text{epi } f$.  We define $f$ to be a *convex function* on $S$ if $\text{epi }f$ is convex as a subset of $R^{n+1}$.

Comment: Can you provide an example. Let's take $z=x^2+y^2$ as the objective function. What is a constraint that will make the locus of intersection with the objective function non-convex?

Comment: Suppose, in your case, the constraint is $|x|+|y|=1$.  The set of constraint-obeying $(x,y)$ is not convex, and questions of optimizing your $z$ might be important, or might be interesting, but will not be answerable by the techniques of convex optimization.  Most or all of the comments on this question seem to think this is _not_ a convex optimization problem, but I gather you do.  Your question, I think, is about a terminological quibble, without mathematical content.